# async data in react-redux child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i just started using react/redux and im facing a problem with async data handling, here i have the parent component (App) that im calling the action creator in to get the data and then passing it to the child component (VideoList)

```
    `class App extends React.Component {
       componentDidMount() {
           this.onFormSubmit()
       }

       state = { selectedVideo: null }

       onVideoClick = (video) => {
           this.setState({selectedVideo: video});
       };

       onFormSubmit = (term) => {
           this.props.fetchList(term)
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <div>
                   <Header/>
                   <div  className="container">
                       <VideoDetail video={this.state.selectedVideo}/>
                       <VideoList videos={this.props.videos}/>
                   </div>
               </div>
           )
       } }

   const mapStateToProps = state => {
       return {videos: state.videos} }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchList})(App)

    `
```

now at the child component im trying to map over the videos array but it keeps telling me that map is not a function, i know that's because the data has not yet come from the youtube api so how can i solve this issue?

note: the app was perfectly functional before trying to setup redux

```
    class VideoList extends React.Component {
    renderList() {
        this.props.videos.map(video => {
            return <VideoItem video={video} onVideoClick={this.onVideoClick} key={video.id.videoId}/>
        });
    };
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.videos);
        return (
            <div> 
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, not rendering `VideoList` if the video list hasn't loaded yet would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your videos in your reducer as an empty array. Then try this:

```
class VideoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.videos.length === 0){
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <div> 
              {this.props.videos.map(video => {
                return <VideoItem
                         video={video}
                         onVideoClick={this.onVideoClick}
                         key={video.id.videoId}
                       />
              }}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you're getting this error because you're trying to map over a list that does not contain any data. You can write some extra logic that says "only execute if the list contains data."

```
renderList() {
    if(this.props.videos){
       this.props.videos.map(video => {
          return <VideoItem video={video} onVideoClick={this.onVideoClick} key={video.id.videoId}/>
       });

    }
};
```

Comment: if(this.props.videos.length) actually removed the error but now when i enter the search term it causes the app to completely refresh and nothing gets rendered

Comment: That likely has to do with your setup in the SearchTerm component itself. You can share that code with us and we can deduce what's wrong. More than likely has to do with how you setup your action creators to be dispatched when typing into search box.

Comment: thank you very much , that solved the problem , the not rendering issue was cuz i didnt wrap the return statement with () lol

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `videos` coming from the reducer is not an array, you just need to set its initial state to `[]`. I'd comment this but I still can't.

Comment: it is set to [] already, in fact i get the empty array console logged before the error.

Comment: So, the first problem is you are not returning the map to be rendered: `return this.props.videos.map(...)`. The second possible problem is that the function `renderList` is not binded, to do that just call it like this: `{this.renderList.bind(this)}`.